# Flatten SetMultiMap and preserve the insertion order

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I am using `LinkedHashMultimap` in my project. I need to flatten the values while preserving the insertion order. For example with

```
SetMultimap<String, Integer> m =  LinkedHashMultimap.create();
m.put("a", 1);
m.put("b",2);
m.put("a",3);
```

I am getting the following output

```
a : [1,3]
b : 2
```

But I need

```
a : 1
b : 2
a : 3
```

or I need the output to be in a List

```
[a,1,b,2,a,3]
```

P.S. I am using `LinkedHashMultimap` because I don't want duplicate `values` for a `key` and I need to preserve the insertion order

How can I do this so I can iterate through the above output for further processing?

Comment: You can create a wrapper class by extending LinkedHashMultiMap and add an array as one of its fields that keeps track on the order exactly like you want it too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Entries](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html#entries--) are returned and are iterated in the order they were inserted so you can do the following to not lose the benefits of `Multimaps`.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : m.entries()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use List inside the map to store multiple values for the same key.

```
    public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Values> list = new LinkedList<Values>();
        list.add(new Values("a", 1));
        list.add(new Values("b", 2));
        list.add(new Values("a", 3));
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}

class Values {
    String key;
    int value;

    public Values(final String key, final int value) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return key + "," + value;
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
[a,1, b,2, a,3]
```

I hope this is how you want it.

Comment: I need a flattened version by preserving the insertion order like `[a,1,b,2,a,3]` @Krishna Kuntala..  If I flatened  your output, I wont get the order. right!

Comment: @user2731629 I hope my updated answer solves your problem with the use of object and a linked list instead of Linked hash map.

Comment: Sorry!!.. Its contains Duplicates. I dont want any duplicate values. if you add a `a,3` again , It shouldnt add it. Thats why I was using SetMuliMap.